# Delete all portrait pages in a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro, and I have a PDF file with 143 pages. It has both landscape and portrait. The portrait pages are meaningless to me. Is there a way I can delete all of the portrait pages? I have tried using the Action Wizard, but I don't think it allows for IF statements.